# (Java) An Array of a class

Tags: java, arrays, helper

I have a class here which gives me back a date in a certain order 
what i want to do is make an array of this class with four type of Dates.

- *May 16, 1984*
- *November 14, 1978*
- *September 21, 1980*
- *July 3, 1987*

How can I fit these dates in the Array ????

```
public class DateArray {

  private String month; 
  private int day; 
  private int year; 


  public DateArray(String n, int d, int y){
    month = n;
    day = d;
    year = y;
  }


  public String toString(){
    return month + "/" + day + "/" + year; 
  }
```

This is what my `Main` looks like right now:

```
DateArray date = new DateArray("jan", 5, 20);
String s =  date.toString();

System.out.println(s);

DateArray [] dates = new DateArray[3];


for(int i =0; i<dates.length; i++)
{
    System.out.println(dates[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't set any values for the array elements in your code example. You need something similar to

```
dates[0] = new DateArray(month, day, year);
```

for each element. Also, I suggest that naming a type 'Array' that isn't an array might be confusing.

Comment: so you saying i should first set my array for example DateArray [] date = nul; ..... then start with my first date for example dates[0] = new DateArray("month,day,year) then keep carrying on to the next?

Comment: No. First, setting the array to  'null' (two ells) means you have no array elements, so attempting to index into it will cause a 'NullPointerException' (NPE). You have to either initialize the array with an array initialization expression as described in the Java Language Specification (JLS) or a 'new Foo[n]' like in your example. If the latter you get n array elements, each of them 'null'. You then set each element to the value you want. I strongly urge you to read and study the Java Tutorial on this matter.

Answer (score 1):

First, based on your expected results, your `DateArray.toString()` should look something like<sup>1</sup>

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return month + " " + day + ", " + year;
}
```

Then you can create and display your array with something like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    DateArray[] dates = new DateArray[] { new DateArray("May", 16, 1984), 
            new DateArray("November", 14, 1978),
            new DateArray("September", 21, 1980), new DateArray("July", 3, 1987) };
    for (DateArray da : dates) {
        System.out.println(da);
    }
}
```

And I get (as requested)

```
May 16, 1984
November 14, 1978
September 21, 1980
July 3, 1987
```

<sup>1<sub>The Override annotation can help you if you think you're correctly overriding a super-type method but you aren't. I suggest you always use it.</sub></sup>